# Windows server users private remote desktop?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop

This may be a really stupid question, and if so I apologize.

I was recently introduced to a "remote desktop" to a windows server, where the user account seemed to have his/her own private VPS type environment, but it was NOT a VPS.

I was told that the server had about 100 users that could log in at any time via this service, and each "desktop" allowed them (each user) to run applications that were installed to their own private locations on the server. In other words, it looked, acted and ran like a VPS - but it was NOT a VPS.

Is this a feature of windows 2012 R2 Datacenter, or is this just good management and setup via Active Directory that makes this work and is secure?

Sorry if this is the wrong type of question for this site - just did not know where else to ask.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/desktop-virtualization

Comment: Cheers - that may be what it is. Ill look in to that.